# Firebase database delete all nodes equalTo a particular value

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of users, which contains a node called `scannedCards`, which contains an array of `cardIds`. Below is a screenshot of one user.

[image: Below is a screenshot of one user]

There are multiple users like above, I want to delete all the card Ids if they are `equalTo(Some Card Id)`, I want to this with all the users at once.

Below is the query I a using:

```
  const ref = database.ref('users');
  const query = ref.orderByChild('cardId').equalTo(cardId);
```

But the result is always empty, Can someone please tell how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query you listed above doesn't seem to be returning anything because, based on the screenshot provided, `cardId` isn't a direct child property of users, but rather a property of each object under the `scannedCards` list that users may have.

If you only need to do this as part of a one-time operation, you may run something like this:

```
const ref = database.ref('users');
ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
  const users = snapshot.val();
  for (var user_id in users) {
    const scannedCards = users[user_id].scannedCards;
    for (var card in scannedCards) {
      if (scannedCards[card].card_id == "<some card id>") {
        firebase.database().ref(`users/${user_id}/scannedCards/${card_id}`)
        .set(null);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

If you plan on letting logged-in users delete their scanned cards, it would be a little bit less complicated:

```
// user_id is for whoever is logged in
const ref = firebase.database().ref(`users/${user_id}/scannedCards`);
ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
  const scannedCards = snapshot.val();
  for (var card in scannedCards) {
    if (scannedCards[card].card_id == "<some card id>") {
      firebase.database().ref(`users/${user_id}/scannedCards/${card_id}`)
      .set(null)
    }
  }
});
```

Also worth pointing out, `scannedCards` is not an array of card ids, because the keys are object ids and the values are objects (which contain cardId and userId properties).

Comment: Great answer Pat! Another alternative would be to add additional data that maps the card ID to the top-level user node. E.g. `"-L4ey...": "n5Id..."`. With this structure you can easily lookup the user for a given card, and then delete/update it in both places.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I thought about it but then I felt like its a bad practice, isn't it?

Comment: What part would be a bad practice. Duplicating data is extremely common in NoSQL databases. See [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), [denormalization is normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) and [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).