# How to delete key+value when value is known

Tags: java, android, firebase

[image]

Like shown in picture, "First Year" is fixed value and I want to find all its occurrences and delete it alongside its key.

I am using Java for Android studio, and I am a noob in writing firebase queries. Please help.

Comment: Can you please export that as JSON and share here so it's easier to reproduce that ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RfiLUi6RjSOhIbtHUzWweccw1JMPwjUz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643090/firebase-database-delete-all-nodes-equalto-a-particular-value did you try this

Comment: @Akash Pal In that example key is fixed and its value may be random. Its opposite in my case.

Comment: You cannot do that with a dynamic node. `Why` and `Kemo` should be fixed.